# Re-organising site layouts and structures

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a requirement where an organisation wants to re-organise their  existing site structure. They have a number of site collections (1 per department) each SC has a number of sub-sites (team sites).

All SC need to to have a new layout with new webparts on the landing pages. All subsites need to have layout changes and maybe navigation changes also. (I'm still looking at the requirements)

Originally, I was under the impression that I was to build all from scratch, this would have been easier. My idea was to create a feature that would build and configure everything in new site collections. As existing site collections exist with sub-sites, how can I achieve the requirements ? All changes need to be mirrored across all existing site collections.

Will this need to be a manual alteration or can it be automated with some sort of template?

Thanks

Comment: I would use a PowerShell script, iterating over the site collections and make the changes needed.